# Looking for book about futuristic technologies sold at school book fairs around 2003

Tags: story-identification, books

Description for the book about future technologies:

- Sold in (some) USA school book fairs around the year 2003
- I thought the title was something like 'Technologies of the future' but again even if that's it the title is super vague and hard to find with a search engine
- Hardcover, greenish cover but might have other colors too
- Large (bit bigger than printer paper size)
- The cover size + glossy look and feel is almost that of a hardcover school yearbook.
- Thin (maybe about 100 pages)
- Glossy, full color pages, lots of pictures with text, some pictures were CGI and some were real
- Every page discusses one or more technologies of the past or the future
- One technology was hovercrafts with a picture of a yellow hovercraft on water and, I think, a picture of a big futuristic hovercraft on water that looked kind of like a grey SR-71 (but I might be mistaking this with something in Halo)
- One of the CGI pictures was about smart homes that could control temperature and showed a rounded purple or pink shape-shifting couch, and I think a light tan/beige staircase, and sensor/control panels near at least one door in the room